# Optional non-boolean attribute in ASP.NET Core 7 Razor

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I want `<li></li>` or `<li aria-current="page"></li>` depending on some condition.

I tried:

```html
<li @(current == Model.CurrentPage ? @"aria-current=\"page\"" : "") ></li>
```

Which gives the incorrect result:

```html
<li aria-current="&quot;page&quot;"></li>
```

There have been many changes in Razor over the years. In v7, is there an easy *one-liner* way to do this? (Without multiline if/else statements, tag helpers, etc.)

(Note that the boolean attribute rendering trick doesn't work here, as I want `<li></li>` rather than `<li aria-current=""></li>`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried as below:

```
<li  aria-current=@(current==Model.Page? "page":null )></li>
```

The result:
[image]

Is this what you want?

Comment: Aaah, the trick is the `null`, the razor compiler is smart enough to exclude the attribute in that case. Nice! Thanks.

Comment: By the way, what tool do you use to make that video?

Comment: I make the gif with ScreenToGif

Comment: @Ionix Razor does not render an attribute at all if the expression passed to it resolves to `null` or `false`.